# How to output a specified percent of all rows from a table?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to output a pre-specified percent, say first 50%, of all rows in my table

The following code is functional, however, is there a better way to achieve this without relying on ID's (as I have done in this code)?

```
SELECT *
FROM WORKER
WHERE WORKER_ID <= (SELECT count(WORKER_ID)/2 from Worker);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`tablesample`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-select.html#SQL-FROM) clause for that:

```
SELECT *
FROM worker TABLESAMPLE system (50);
```

The manual also explains the built-in sampling methods:

> The standard PostgreSQL distribution includes two sampling methods, BERNOULLI and SYSTEM, and other sampling methods can be installed in the database via extensions. [...] The SYSTEM method is significantly faster than the BERNOULLI method when small sampling percentages are specified, but it may return a less-random sample of the table as a result of clustering effects.

Comment: Tried running the code and I'm getting some strange behavior. Using SYSTEM sampling, half of the time I'm getting no output, the other half, I'm getting all rows. Using BERNOULLI returns a varying number of rows (not 50%)

Comment: It's a table with just 8 rows

Comment: For a tiny table like that, SYSTEM isn't usable indeed because of the block sampling (the table probably only has a single block. Not sure why bernoulli works so strangely, but maybe it's also cause by the fact that sampling such a small number of rows simply isn't reliable (the percentage is just an approximate value)

Answer (score 0):

If you want exactly half the rows, then I would suggest counting.  You don't specify if you want a *random* sample:

```
select w.*
from (select w.*, row_number() over (order by random()) as seqnum,
             count(*) over () as cnt
      from worker w
     ) w
where seqnum <= cnt / 2;
```

or:

```
select *
from t
order by random()
limit (select count(*) / 2 from t);
```

If you don't want a random sample, you can remove the `order by`.

The `tablesample` methods are not guaranteed to return *exactly* half the rows.